# Makefile for kernel module doesn't work after ubuntu upgrade

Tags: makefile, kernel-module, ubuntu-14.04

I have upgraded my ubuntu from 13.10 to 14.04 and I need to rebuild a kernel module provided by Agilent for the USBTmc.
The Makefile content is:

```
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
obj-m   := usbtmc.o
else
KDIR    := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)
default:
$(MAKE) -C $(KDIR)  SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
endif
```

But it raises a syntax error near the token

```
"$(KERNELRELEASE),"./Makefile: riga 1: `ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)'
```

what I must do? Do I need to download something new for the new kernel?

thanks in advance

Comment: solved with apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)

Comment: @Silver You should post this as an answer and accept it.